# GitHubとSource Treeの使い方を教えてください

Tags: git, github

GitHubの使い方についてよくわかるサイトなどをなるべくたくさん教えて下さい。初心者です。Source Treeの使い方もよくわからないので、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 具体的な内容の質問を心がけ、「なるべくたくさん」など一つの回答で定まらないものは避けるべきです。
加えて「初心者です。」という言葉はあなたのスキルを表したとしても、Q&Aサイトの使い方について免罪符にはなりません。

Answer (score 5):

GitHub/Git関連

[GitHub Help - GitHub Enterprise  Documentation](https://help.github.com/)
GitHub公式のHelp

[海外Webサービスのトリセツ（4）：GitHub（ギットハブ）の使い方：登録編 - ＠IT](http://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/1407/22/news019.html)
GitHubの使い方を登録から日本語で解説している

[Qiita GitHub](https://qiita.com/tags/github)
QiitaのGitHubについての投稿が集まっているページ

[サルでもわかるGit入門](http://www.backlog.jp/git-guide/)
わかりやすいGit(GitHubではない)の使い方

[git入門 (全22回) - プログラミングならドットインストール](http://dotinstall.com/lessons/basic_git)
Gitの基本的なことについて3分動画で学べる

[Qiita Git](https://qiita.com/tags/git)
QiitaのGitについての投稿が集まっているページ

---

SourceTree関連

[リポジトリの作成と基本的なバージョン管理――SourceTreeで始めるGitバージョン管理入門 第1回 | OSDN Magazine](http://osdn.jp/magazine/14/11/06/200000)
SourceTreeの基本的な部分の記事

[Qiita SourceTree](https://qiita.com/tags/sourcetree)
QiitaのSourceTreeについての投稿が集まっているページ

Comment: git については（事実上 man ですが）http://git-scm.com/docs とかもいいですね．